# Can't launch my app on my XCODE 12.5.1, with Flutter 1.22

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, flutter

I was working an application. Before that i was using another version of XCode,
( I don't remember which one)but finally the iOs emulator didn't work and I had to change to the new version of xCode 12.5.1. My code is using Flutter 1.22. But when i try to launch my Xcode build i Have this type of error.

```
/Users/macbookair/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-4.0.1/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:9: note: did you mean 'tapToDismissEnabled'?
 @param allowTapToDismiss
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        tapToDismissEnabled
/Users/macbookair/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-4.0.1/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:362:20: warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param' command [-Wdocumentation]
 @param queueEnabled
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
/Users/macbookair/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-4.0.1/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:19:23: warning: unused variable 'viewController' [-Wunused-variable]
    UIViewController *viewController =
                      ^
/Users/macbookair/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-4.0.1/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:70:21: warning: unused variable 'topPadding' [-Wunused-variable]
            CGFloat topPadding = window.safeAreaInsets.top;
                    ^
/Users/macbookair/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-4.0.1/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:71:21: warning: unused variable 'bottomPadding' [-Wunused-variable]
            CGFloat bottomPadding = window.safeAreaInsets.bottom;
                    ^
/Users/macbookair/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-4.0.1/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:48:19: warning: unused variable 'size' [-Wunused-variable]
        NSNumber *size = call.arguments[@"size"];
                  ^
8 warnings generated.
/Users/macbookair/Desktop/Keatov /App/app/ios/Pods/Reachability/Reachability.m:465:63: warning: cast to smaller integer type 'unsigned int' from 'Reachability *' [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
                             NSStringFromClass([self class]), (unsigned int) self, [self currentReachabilityFlags]];
                                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
/Users/macbookair/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_device_locale-0.4.0/ios/Classes/FlutterDeviceLocalePlugin.m:2:9: fatal error: 'flutter_device_locale/flutter_device_locale-Swift.h' file not found
#import <flutter_device_locale/flutter_device_locale-Swift.h>
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Analyzing workspace
note: Constructing build description
note: Build preparation complete
```

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.
Exited (sigterm)

Answer (score 1):

the error is from one of the plugin that you are using, the "flutter_device_locale" plugin

I recommend using device_info_plus, which is also a flutter favorite,
here's a link https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus

Comment: Thank you but I Don't see any package on my pubspec.yaml file who's named "flutter_device_locale". How can I change this plug-in ? And where ? Thank You

Comment: that's weird, based on what you posted it should be there,maybe one of the packages depends on it? try running 'flutter clean' and 'flutter pub cache repair' and rebuild